# i cannot call my php function within javascript code

Tags: php, jquery

i'm working with signup page using PHP and i validate my Signup form using JQuery...When i call my PHP function within the code of JQuery i cannot get my output....
i want to do that when user filled all the fields with proper format then the php signup function call which insert the data in the database

**HERE IS MY CODE FOR PHP AND JQUERY**

```
<?php
    function signup(){
        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
        $mail=$_POST["mail"];
        $pass=$_POST["pass"];
        $repass=$_POST["repass"];
        $country=$_POST["country"];
        $city=$_POST["city"];
        $day=$_POST["day"];
        $month=$_POST["month"];
        $year=$_POST["year"];
        $gender=$_POST["name"];

        //echo $name." ".$lastname." ".$pass." ".$repass." ".$mail." ".$country." ".$city." ".$day." ".$month." ".$year." ".$gender;
    }
  ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reg-btn").click(function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        var mail = $("#mail").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();
        var repass = $("#repass").val();
        var country = $("#country").val();
        var city = $("#city").val();
        var day = $("#day").val();
        var month = $("#month").val();
        var year = $("#year").val();
        var gender = $("#gender").val();
       if( !$('#name').val() ||  !$('#lastname').val() || !$('#mail').val() || !$('#pass').val() || !$('#repass').val() || !$('#country').val() || !$('#city').val() || !$('#day').val() || !$('#month').val() || !$('#year').val() || !$('#gender').val()) {
            $("#error").html("Please Fill all Fields");
            return false;
    }else{
            var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            var nameRegex=/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
            var passRegex=/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/;
            if(nameRegex.test(name)){
               if(nameRegex.test(lastname)){
                   if(emailRegex.test(mail)){
                       if(passRegex.test(pass)){
                           if(repass==pass){
                               if(nameRegex.test(country)){
                                   if(nameRegex.test(city)){
                                       <?php signup();?>
                                   }else{$("#error").html("invalid City Name");return false;};
                               }else{$("#error").html("invalid Country Name");return false;};
                           }else{$("#error").html("Passwords do not Match");return false;};
                       }else{$("#error").html("invalid Password");return false;};
                   }else{$("#error").html("invalid Email Address");return false;};
               }else{$("#error").html("invalid Last Name");return false;};
            }else{$("#error").html("invalid First Name");return false;}
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You  can't use your php(server) function as a clientside function.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JavaScript (in this case) on the client / browser. You can't directly call PHP functions in JavaScript.

Comment: push it hard, maybe it will work eventually :)

Comment: If you need to execute PHP code from a JS event then you can use AJAX. There are lots of questions and tutorials about this already, if you search. The marked duplicate has a thorough explanation of the differences between server and client code which I suggest you familiarise yourself with.

Comment: @Jon Stirling then what should i do?? any other way to do it??

Comment: Call an Ajax function that runs a PHP script with the PHP function in it.